# What is the proper way to nest data into python dictionary?

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

```
class ldapDict():
    jsonStruct={}

def add_keys_nested_dict(d, keys):
    if len(keys) == 1:
        d.setdefault(keys[0], 1)
    else:
        key = keys[0]
        if key not in d:
            d[key] = {}
        add_keys_nested_dict(d[key], keys[1:])

def listSplit(input):
    dnList=input.split(',')
    res = [i for i in dnList if i not in ldapSearchBase.split(',')]
    if(len(res)<=1):
        primaryKey=ldapSearchBase
        parent=ldapSearchBase
    else:
        primaryKey=res[0]
        parent=res[1]
    return (parent,primaryKey)

def dissectList(input):
    x=listSplit(input)
    add_keys_nested_dict(ldapDict.jsonStruct,x)
```

This is the portion of code that takes the ldap "DN" data and builds the dictionary from that path. The output is not nesting the data to the right "parent".

```
{
  "dc=ZZ,dc=org": {
    "dc=ZZ,dc=org": 1
  },
  "dc=dows": {
    "ou=users": 1,
    "ou=userunit": 1,
    "ou=unittypemaster": 1
  },
  "ou=unittypemaster": {
    "accessunittypemasterkey=A": 1,
    "accessunittypemasterkey=B": 1,
    "accessunittypemasterkey=C": 1,
    "accessunittypemasterkey=D": 1,
    "accessunittypemasterkey=E": 1,
    "accessunittypemasterkey=F": 1
  }, ...
```

This is a snippet of the output. dc=ZZ,dc=org is the root, but dc=dows should be nested in dc=ZZ,dc=org. Similarly ou=unittypemaster should be nested into that spot in dc=dows. I know the issues is in how I am looking into the dictionary, but I can't figure out the correct way to drill down.

Comment: What's the input?

Answer (score 0):

```
def addEntry(path, itemInfo):
    current = ldapDict.jsonStruct
    for item in path[:-1]:
        if item not in current:
            current[item] = {}
        current = current[item]
    current[path[-1]] = itemInfo

    for item in path[:-1]:
        current = ldapDict.jsonStruct
        for key in path[:-1]:
            if key not in current:
                current[key] = {}
            current = current[key]

def processPath(path,itemInfo):
    dn = path["dn"].split(",")
    dn.reverse()  # Reverse to build from innermost to outermost
    addEntry(dn,itemInfo)
```

This worked well for me. Just took a while of looking at the issue.

Comment: Please fix the indentation.